# Deploy/Publish VS 2008 Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment

What is the best method to deploy an VS 2008 Web Application? My web application contains webservice references, libraries etc and i have to publish this to my production server which has iis 6.0 on it. 
Should i use VS Web Deployment method? Should i go with pre compilation and publsih the website? I am confused as you can see :).. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not use VS Web Deployment. I build them on VS and deploy them manually with FTP Client.